# Contact form 7 database extension query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pivot-table, contact-form-7

I am using below query:

```
SELECT `submit_time` AS 'Submitted',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-name', `field_value`, null )) AS 'your-name',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-email', `field_value`, null )) AS 'your-email',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-phone', `field_value`, null )) AS 'your-phone',
 max(if(`field_name`='Submitted From', `field_value`, null )) AS 'Submitted From',
 GROUP_CONCAT(if(`file` is null or length(`file`) = 0, null, `field_name`)) AS 'fields_with_file'
FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
WHERE `form_name` = 'test form'  
GROUP BY `submit_time` 
ORDER BY `submit_time` DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

This returned me top 100 rows(All fields values are present).

What i want is to get a particular row .For this i had appended above query at WHERE clause section with this line `( AND field_name='your-email' AND field_value = 'test@gm.com')`.
Now the final query is:

```
SELECT `submit_time` AS 'Submitted',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-name', `field_value`, null )) AS 'your-name',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-email', `field_value`, null )) AS 'your-email',
 max(if(`field_name`='your-phone', `field_value`, null )) AS 'your-phone',
 max(if(`field_name`='Submitted From', `field_value`, null )) AS 'Submitted From',
 GROUP_CONCAT(if(`file` is null or length(`file`) = 0, null, `field_name`)) AS 'fields_with_file'
FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` 
WHERE `form_name` = 'test form'  AND field_name=your-email AND field_value = 'test@gm.com'
GROUP BY `submit_time` 
ORDER BY `submit_time` DESC
```

but its only returned your-email value  and other fields value becomes NULL(Like your-name field is NULL).

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this/where I can find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The query you started with is a summary query (it has a `GROUP BY` clause and a bunch of aggregate functions like `MAX` and `GROUP_CONCAT`).  The table you're querying from is a tag-value table.  That is, the rows contain

```
 submit-time    form-name   field-name    field-value
   (time)      test-form    your-email      test@gm.com
   (time)      test-form    your-name       Priya the Tester
```

etcetera. The purpose of the query you started with is to "pivot" this table, that is, transform it into a result set with rows like this.  It does it by correlating the various rows in the table by using `GROUP BY submit-time` (which is a remarkably bad way of doing that in a busy system, but never mind). The pivoted rows look approximately like this.

```
    submit-time your-email     your-name
     (time)      test@gm.com   Priya the tester
```

So, to select just one "row" of this "result" you need to be a little smarter than just filtering the rows of the original table. You could try

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM (
       /* the entire original query */
         ) AS pivoted
  WHERE pivoted.`your-email` = 'test@gm.com'
```

It won't be terribly efficient, but it will work.